# Como fazer uma tabela de distribuição de frequência em Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Boa tarde,

Uma dúvida:
Alguém poderia me esclarecer sobre como posso fazer uma tabela de distribuição de frequência: classes; frequência absoluta e relativa; de forma acumulada; valores médios de cada classe.

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito genérica! Você não mostrou os dados que você tem (ao menos uma pequena amostra, para saber como trabalhar) e o que você já fez e como está tentando implementar. Quase tudo o que você quer é possivel fazer com as funcões do numpy/scipy.

Answer (score 2):

Oi, eu consegui criar uma... Vou te mandar o exemplo usando o Pandas e talvez ainda lhe ajude!

**Cálculos necessários para gerar a tabela:** Amplitude da Classe **(h)** através da relação  **h=AT/k**, em que **AT=max(x) − min(x)** é a amplitude total dos dados e **k = raiz(n)** é um número estimado de intervalos de classes para um conjunto de dados com n observações (k pode ser calculado por outras definições, como a regra de Sturges, por exemplo).

Criação da tabela - Suponhamos que você também vá usar um DataFrame pandas

1 - Ordenação dos valores do dataframe

```
df = data['fixed acidity']
df.sort_values(ascending=True)
```

2 - Calcule a Amplitude Total dos dados

```
# Amplitude dos dados = Valor maior dos registros - menor valor
at = df.max() - df.min()
```

3 - Calcule a Amplitude da Classe

```
  # Lembrando que k = raiz quadrada do total de registros/amostras
    k = math.sqrt(len(df))
    # O valor de amplitude de classe pode ser arredondado para um número inteiro, geralmente para facilitar a interpretação da tabela.
    h = at/k 
    h = math.ceil(h)
```

4 - Gerar tabela de frequências

```
frequencias = []

# Menor valor da série
menor = round(df.min(),1)

# Menor valor somado a amplitude
menor_amp = round(menor+h,1)

valor = menor
while valor < df.max():
    frequencias.append('{} - {}'.format(round(valor,1),round(valor+h,1)))
    valor += h
```

5 - Distribuição de frequências:

```
freq_abs = pd.qcut(df,len(frequencias),labels=frequencias) # Discretização dos valores em k faixas, rotuladas pela lista criada anteriormente
print(pd.value_counts(freq_abs))
```

Referência dos cálculos e alguns exemplos utilizados: https://www.inf.ufsc.br/~andre.zibetti/probabilidade/aed.html#vari%C3%A1vel_quantitativa_discreta

Comment: Se alguém souber uma forma mais fácil/melhor de fazer isso pode me ensinar por favor, foi a melhor forma que encontrei :)

Comment: Devido a pergunta ser muito ampla, não consigo confirmar se isso realmente atende corretamente ao solicitado. No entanto,foi uma ótima explicação Gabi , obrigado por partilhar!

Comment: De nada! Imaginei que seria isso rs